# How to resolve custom list view  while scrolling checking condition not working properly

Tags: android

I have implemented custom list view with arrayadapter. using Arraylist  data object i am setting value for list view row .using data object value I am checking condition if the value is seller i am visble the row.  when i am scrolling its not working properly.it is visible for some other value also.can anybody tell what is problem how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: ya dude listview always creates problem like this +1

Comment: Hi mohan its getView() method of your arrayadapter which is causing problem.. getView() method get called many time .. and every time it draws every row of list again .. please post your code so that we can try to solve it

Comment: You use **ViewHolder** for list item then it will works.

Comment: @silwar i am not able to post the code

Comment: just edit your post with the code

Comment: @silwar what i am trying to say is i shouldn't post my code

Comment: @anil I have used view holder also still not working